# How to combine a Self-organising map and a multilayer perceptron in python

Tags: python, neural-network, cluster-analysis, image-recognition, self-organizing-maps

I am working on a image recognition project in python. I have read in journals that if clustering performed by a self-organizing map (SOM) is input into a supervised neural network the accuracy of image recognition improves as opposed to the supervised network on its own. I have tried this myself by using the SOM to perform clustering and then using the coordinates of the winning neuron after each iteration as input to a multilayer perceptron from the keras. However the accuracy is very poor.

What output of SOM should be used as input to a multilayer perceptron?

Comment: I don't now if I correct understand. You first train the SOM layer and afther unsupervised training you give MLP winning neuron coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I first train the SOM which clusters the images that I input into it. After the unsupervised training of the SOM, I store the winning x,y coordinates in a 2d numpy array and I supply this to the MLP as input but the test accuracy of the MLP is really low so I waa wondering if there was another way to combine a SOM and MLP other than supplying the coordinates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hybrid SOM (with MLP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434218/hybrid-som-with-mlp)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use SOM is for vector quantisation. Rather than using the winning SOM coordinates, use the codebook values of the winning neuron. Not sure which articles you are reading, but I would have said that SOM into MLP will only provide better accuracy in certain cases. Also, you will need to choose parameters like dimensionality and map size wisely.

For image processing, I would have said that Autoencoders or Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) are more cutting-edge alternatives to SOM to investigate if you're not determined on the SOM + MLP architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering if there is any mileage to training a separate supervised neural network for the inputs which map to each node in the SOM. You'd then have separate supervised learning on the subset of the input data mapping to each SOM node. The networks attached to each node would perhaps be smaller and more easily trained than one large network which had to deal with the whole input space. There may also be benefit from including input vectors which map to the adjacent SOM nodes.

Is anyone aware of this being the subject of research?